# average of first 3 items from list using linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, average

I have cobbled together what I thought would have been a solution to what I wanted to do based on other threads on here on this topic (return a specific number of items from a list) but I think my syntax is a little of and it is not allowing me to sum the items I have taken.

Here is what I have:

```
public decimal average_of_items_examples(List<Car> cars)
        {
            if (cars == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (cars.Count == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return cars.OrderBy(x => x.SuggestedRetailPrice).Take(3).Average();
            }
        }
```

I appreciate any help and appreciate explanations.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to add why I have the OrderBy part. I only want the average of the 3 less expensive cars.

NOTE: I can not change the type "decimal" as this is how the exercise was written.

Comment: What are you trying to average? The SuggestedRetailPrice?

Comment: Yes. I believe so, as that is the only logical parameter that is a decimal value.

Comment: Sorry I added clarifying information that I only want to the average price of the 3 least expensive cars in the list, hence my original "OrderBy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both:

```
cars.OrderBy(x => x.SuggestedRetailPrice).Take(3).Select(z => z.SuggestedRetailPrice).Average();
```

and:

```
cars.Select(z => z.SuggestedRetailPrice).OrderBy(x => x).Take(3).Average();
```

will do what you need.

*They are both basically the same.*

Answer (score 3):

```
.Average(x => x.SuggestedRetailPrice)
```

You have to specify the property you want to get average of since the collection is for `Car` objects